# NLTK word tokenize behaviour for double quotation marks is confusing

Tags: python, nltk

```
import nltk
>>> nltk.__version__
'3.0.4'
>>> nltk.word_tokenize('"')
['``']
>>> nltk.word_tokenize('""')
['``', '``']
>>> nltk.word_tokenize('"A"')
['``', 'A', "''"]
```

See how it changes `"` to a double `` and `''`?

What's happening here? Why is it changing the character? Is there a fix? As I need to search for each token in the string later on.

Python 2.7.6 if it makes any difference.

Comment: It allows to avoid the errors (how to escape correctly `"`?) If you want to change it you can update [the source](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html#PunktLanguageVars.word_tokenize). But you also can replace the wrong characters in your list of tokens...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

`nltk.word_tokenize` changes starting double quotes changes from ``` " -> `` ``` and ending double quotes from `" -> ''`.

---

**In long**:

First the `nltk.word_tokenize` tokenizes base on how Penn TreeBank  was tokenized, it comes from `nltk.tokenize.treebank`, see [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/**init**.py#L91](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py#L91) and https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/treebank.py#L23

```
class TreebankWordTokenizer(TokenizerI):
    """
    The Treebank tokenizer uses regular expressions to tokenize text as in Penn Treebank.
    This is the method that is invoked by ``word_tokenize()``.  It assumes that the
    text has already been segmented into sentences, e.g. using ``sent_tokenize()``.
```

Then comes a list of regex replacements for contractions at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/treebank.py#L48, it comes from the "**Robert MacIntyre's tokenizer**", i.e. https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/tokenizer.sed

The contractions splits words like "gonna", "wanna", etc.:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> word_tokenize("I wanna go home")
['I', 'wan', 'na', 'go', 'home']
>>> word_tokenize("I gonna go home")
['I', 'gon', 'na', 'go', 'home']
```

After that we reach the punctuation part that you're asking about, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/treebank.py#L63:

```
def tokenize(self, text):
    #starting quotes
    text = re.sub(r'^\"', r'``', text)
    text = re.sub(r'(``)', r' \1 ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'([ (\[{<])"', r'\1 `` ', text)
```

Ah ha, starting quotes changes from **"->``**:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '"A"'
>>> re.sub(r'^\"', r'``', text)
'``A"'
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> re.sub(r'(``)', r' \1 ', re.sub(r'^\"', r'``', text))
' `` A"'
>>> re.sub(r'([ (\[{<])"', r'\1 `` ', re.sub(r'(``)', r' \1 ', re.sub(r'^\"', r'``', text)))
' `` A"'
>>> text_after_startquote_changes = re.sub(r'([ (\[{<])"', r'\1 `` ', re.sub(r'(``)', r' \1 ', re.sub(r'^\"', r'``', text)))
>>> text_after_startquote_changes
' `` A"'
```

Then we see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/treebank.py#L85 that deals with ending quotes:

```
    #ending quotes
    text = re.sub(r'"', " '' ", text)
    text = re.sub(r'(\S)(\'\')', r'\1 \2 ', text)
```

Applying the regexes:

```
>>> re.sub(r'"', " '' ", text_after_startquote_changes)
" `` A '' "
>>> re.sub(r'(\S)(\'\')', r'\1 \2 ', re.sub(r'"', " '' ", text_after_startquote_changes))
" `` A '' "
```

---

So if you want to search the list of tokens for double quotes after `nltk.word_tokenize`, simply search for ``` `` ``` and `''` instead of `"`.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem possible to easily process quoted words in any nltk tokenizer.

- single quote words are split with the start quote attached to it, and end quote as next token
- double quote are split as two single quote, depending the tokenizer, producing 2 tokens before and 2 after the word, or 1 token of 2 single quote before, and 2 single quote after.
- you shall search for these tokens

```py
s = "marked with ''gonzaga'' "
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
word_tokenize(s)
['marked', 'with', '``', 'gonzaga', "''"]
from sacremoses  import MosesTokenizer
tokenizer = MosesTokenizer()
tokenizer.tokenize(s, escape=False)
['marked', 'with', "'", "'", 'gonzaga', "'", "'"]
```